# Why does my controller seem to not have the event slot 'onShowClick'?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I started to work with JavaFx Scene Builder and Eclipse. I encountered a problem many people encountered before (also on this platform). Still I seem not to find the solution. As the title describes, it says there is no event called 'onShowClick' in my controller even though I have one implemented. I hope someone can spot my mistake.

error:

```
The controller 'SampleController' has no event slot 'onShowClick'
```

fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="800.0" style="-fx-background-color: #32B66F;" stylesheets="@application.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.SampleController">
   <children>
      <ListView layoutX="154.0" layoutY="114.0" prefHeight="356.0" prefWidth="493.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 1em;" stylesheets="@application.css" />
      <Label layoutX="183.0" layoutY="24.0" stylesheets="@application.css" text="Appointments" textFill="#73d6a1">
         <font>
            <Font name="Bauhaus 93" size="72.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <ImageView fitHeight="41.0" fitWidth="47.0" layoutX="745.0" layoutY="14.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../2020-03-13_15-12-06.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Button fx:id="show" graphicTextGap="2.0" layoutX="167.0" layoutY="433.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onShowClick" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="70.0" style="-fx-background-color: #E1E1E1;" stylesheets="@application.css" text="Show" />
      <Button fx:id="delete" graphicTextGap="2.0" layoutX="481.0" layoutY="433.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="22.0" prefWidth="70.0" style="-fx-background-color: #CE4B4B;" styleClass="delBtn" stylesheets="@application.css" text="Delete" textFill="WHITE" />
      <Button fx:id="newItem" graphicTextGap="2.0" layoutX="563.0" layoutY="433.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="22.0" prefWidth="70.0" style="-fx-background-color: #02813C;" stylesheets="@application.css" text="New" textFill="WHITE" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

controller class:

```
package application;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class SampleController {

    @FXML
    private Button show;

    @FXML
    private Button delete;

    @FXML
    private Button newItem;

    @FXML
    void onShowClick(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("show");
    }

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Wrong `ActionEvent` import. You're not actually using the parameter anyway, so you can just omit it.

Comment: Ah nice thanks @James_D